# Forbidden in Call connection Android Pjsip Sip library

Tags: android, sip, pjsip

**How to perform call in Pjsip Android with local server?**

I used
User-Agent: Pjsua2 Android 2.6-svn

I made successful registraion after which i tried to call but it throws forbidden(503)
My Registraion Code :

```
     AccountConfig accCfg = new AccountConfig();
        accCfg.setIdUri("sip:localhost");
        accCfg.getNatConfig().setIceEnabled(true);
        accCfg.getVideoConfig().setAutoTransmitOutgoing(true);
        accCfg.getVideoConfig().setAutoShowIncoming(true);
     //Like 123.12.12.23 
       accCfg.getRegConfig().setRegistrarUri("sip:172.16.4.124");

        AuthCredInfoVector creds = accCfg.getAuthCreds();
        creds.clear();
        if (username.length() != 0) {
           creds.add(new AuthCredInfo("Digest", "*", "abc@172.16.4.124", 0,
            "123"));
                    }
         StringVector proxies = accCfg.getSipConfig().getProxies();
                    proxies.clear();
                    if (proxy.length() != 0) {
                        proxies.add("sip:172.16.4.124");
                    }                                  
           accCfg.getSipConfig().setProxies(proxies);

        /* Enable ICE */
                    accCfg.getNatConfig().setIceEnabled(true);
                    try {
                        account.add(accCfg);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.i(TAG, "Exception in Dialog");
                    }
                }
```

For Making call I used

```
public void makeCall(View view) {
    if (buddyListSelectedIdx == -1)
        return;

/* Only one call at anytime */
    if (currentCall != null) {
        return;
    }

    HashMap<String, String> item = (HashMap<String, String>) buddyListView.
            getItemAtPosition(buddyListSelectedIdx);
    String buddy_uri = item.get("uri");

    MyCall call = new MyCall(account, -1);
    SendInstantMessageParam param = new SendInstantMessageParam();
    param.setContent("Hello Pjsip");
    param.setContentType("text");


    CallOpParam prm = new CallOpParam(true);

    try {
        call.makeCall(buddy_uri, prm);
//            call.delete();
//            call.sendInstantMessage(param);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        call.delete();
        return;
    }
    currentCall = call;
    showCallActivity();

}
```

I am able to connect call with sip default client like sip:localhost and other sip provider like linphone but getting forbidden with our server.
Experts please help.

Comment: please post your log of forbidden response message.

Comment: I am able to connect it with local also but voice is not coming at either side, then i do setup over amazon where same,  call not connecting with our client getting request timeout error while works other client, please advice.

Comment: If you want to establish call on **local server**, you must connect your device and local server on same LAN.

Comment: You need to add port in all SIP Address like Registrar URI , Proxies, Credentials as SIP:172.16.4.124:5060 with port. Try this one first!

Answer (score -1):

**Thanks alot to myself, finally i get the solution after 3 day workout, 
had missing portnumber for my amazon server, makes me to get connected and made a sippy call between sip ends.**